# Generalization of Cartesian Product with Shared Actions for Reactive Graphs

Tags: computer-science, algebras

The defnitions of Reactive Graph are the follow:

Multi-Action Reactive Graph of order $n$ is a structure $M = (w, \mathcal{F} ,\mathcal{A})$ where:

- $w \in Q $ is the current state;
- $\mathcal{F} = (Q,Act,E,HE)$ is the frame of MAR where:
  -$Q$ is the set of states non empty;
  -$Act$ is the set of actions;
  -$E \subseteq  Q \times Q \times Act$ is the set of level 0 edges;
  -$HE$ is the set of higher-level edges, where:
  $$\begin{cases}
              HE_1 \subseteq  E \times E \times \{ ON, OFF \}; \\  
              HE_2 \subseteq  E \times HE_1 \times \{ ON, OFF \}\; \bigcup \;HE_1 \times E \times \{ ON, OFF \}; \\
              \qquad \vdots  \\
              HE_{k+1} \subseteq  \bigcup_{i=0}^k \left( HE_{i} \times HE_{k-i} \times \{ ON, OFF \}  \right) \text{, with } HE_0 = E \\
          \end{cases}$$
  So, $HE = \bigcup_{i=1}^n HE_i$, where $n$ is the highest order.

-$\mathcal{A} \subseteq E \cup HE$ is a set that indicates if one edge are enable os disable.

If we consider a LTS (Labelled transition System), basicaly, is the reactive graph (RG) without hyper edges and every edges are enable. And, I want generalise the product with shared actions between  RG from the definition for LTS. The definition for LTS, is the following:

$$\begin{array}{c}
  s_1 \xrightarrow{a}_1 s1' ~\quad~
    a \in Act_1 \backslash Act_2
  \\\hline
  (s_1,s_2) ~ \xrightarrow{a}  ~  (s'_1,s_2)
  \end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c}
  s_2 \xrightarrow{a}_2 s2' ~\quad~
    a \in Act_2 \backslash Act_1
  \\\hline
  (s_1,s_2) ~ \xrightarrow{a}  ~  (s1,s'_2)
  \end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c}
  s_1 \xrightarrow{a}_1 s1' ~\quad~ s_2 \xrightarrow{a}_2 s2' ~\quad~ a \in Act_1 \cap Act_2
  \\\hline
  (s_1,s_2) ~ \xrightarrow{a}  ~  (s'_1,s'_2)
  \end{array}$$

For the level 0 edges, the problem is solved, these rules work prefectly. However, for hyper edges the problem its not trivial, because a hyper edge can start from an edge that exists and arrive at one that does not exist.

Any hint is welcome to progress. I would be really grateful.